# 'Import image as planes' Image fading in animation

Tags: image, shader-nodes

my image is fading during my animation; how can i prevent this. this is making my animation look vey unrealistic.[image]

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1h2cdI64SwF2_oFxhuQuAnM4VJQG2C61u/view?usp=sharing

this is an image sequence of 6 frames.
► I am referring to the background of trees. in the first image(red circle) the trees are there and as each frame passes to the last frame(red circle) . the image as plane disappears.

Comment: There's no way to tell just from that image without more details. https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please look at link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1h2cdI64SwF2_oFxhuQuAnM4VJQG2C61u/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Sorry but 6 frames from a video doesn't help. You will need to show your Blender settings and share the Blend file if anyone is going to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

forgive me , it was simply a matter of adjusting "Clip End".

cheers m8,

[image]